# openpyxl - Add data validation for dependent list

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to create a dependent drop down list using openpyxl. Defining the named ranges and populating the first dropdown list using the `DataValidation` module works fine.

However, for the dependent list to work, the second drop down list needs to use an Excel formula. It seems, I cannot supply that via openpyxl.

Here is the code I use that fails:

```
dv = DataValidation(type='list', formula1="'INDIRECT(B16)'")
sheet.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add('A19:A33')
```

Manually adding the formula `=INDIRECT(B16)` to the cell in Excel works. And using a custom type (rather than a list) is possible but obviously does not have the intended drop down functionality, i.e.:

```
dv = DataValidation(type='custom', formula1="'=INDIRECT(B16)'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totatlly following your example. I did try to run your code and got an error when manually opening the excel workbook after running the code. After reading some of the [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html), I updated the code by slightly changing the forumula1 part, and I no longer got an error.

Again, not sure if this is what you were looking for or not.

```
dv = DataValidation(type='list', formula1="=INDIRECT(B16)")
sheet.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add('A19:A33')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did was providing a list consisting of a single text-valued element of `INDIRECT(B16)`. In the workbook created this way, if you change the type of B column to "text" and type in `INDIRECT(B16)` in the cell B16, it will be accepted by the data validation mechanism.

This happens when you include double quotes `"` in the raw string by typing `formula1='"INDIRECT(B16)"'`. The underlying mechanism of `openpyxl` will treat this value as text. Note that you need to include double quotes `"` rather than single quotes `'` in the raw string supplied to `DataValidation`, as doing the latter (as in your example
`dv = DataValidation(type='list',formula1="'INDIRECT(B16)'"`) results in a corrupted xlsx file.

To achieve the result you wanted, you need to provide a value of type <class ‘str’> without any double quotes included in it:

```py
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1="INDIRECT(B16)")
```

I presume you included double quotes `"` in your code trying to adapt
[an example from openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html):

```py
>>> # Create a data-validation object with list validation
>>> dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"Dog,Cat,Bat"', allow_blank=True)
```

Note that the intention of this example was to create a list with 3 text-valued elements of `Dog`, `Cat` and `Bat`. Per [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.html#openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation), values of `formula1` must be of type <class ‘str’>. The double quotes in this example were included in the raw string to let excel know that this argument of type <class ‘str’> contains a list of custom text values rather than a reference to any existing range or excel function.